# Find most distant point all other points in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this simple problem.  I have been searching the forums and altought I have gotten closer to an answer this is not exactly what I need.

I'm trying to find from a set of x,y points which point is the furthest away from any other points i.e. not the maximum distance between points, but the one furthest from the rest.

I've tried

```
x <-c(x1,x2,x3....)
y <-c(y1,y2,y3...)
dist(cbind(x,y))
```

Which gives me a matrix of the distance between each point to each point.  I can interrogate the data in MS Excel and find the answer.  Find the minimum values in each column, then the maximum number across them.

[image]

If I were to plot the data, I would like to have as output the distance of either the red or blue line (depending on which is longer).

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that this problem is well specified as it stands. What is the function that you are using to aggregate the distances from a particular point?

Comment: what is your definition of rest? Because, essentially, you are trying to find the observation that is an outlier given the whole data set. Usually, on would do that by finding the observations the lie mor distant only in terms of a single column (variable/feature) but you are trying to compare against the whole 'blob', see?

Comment: sorry if the question isn't clear enough - I've added an image in the original post that hopefully shows what I'm trying to do.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: interrogate data?

Comment: By interrogate the data I can look for each point look up the minimum distance from any another point, then look up the maximum distance across the set of minimums.

Comment: @Adam I advise you to add some real data and have also mentioned the desired solution

Comment: @amonk Either me have misunderstood the question or....? Coz I keep up on seeing completely different answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from this example data set:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(150)
y <- rnorm(150)
coord <- cbind(x,y)
dobj <- dist(coord)
```

Now `dobj` is a distance object, but you can't examine that directly. You'll have to convert that to a matrix first, and make sure you don't take zero distances between a point and itself into account:

```
dmat <- as.matrix(dobj)
diag(dmat) <- NA
```

The latter line replaces the diagonal values in the distance matrix with `NA`.

Now you can use the solution of amonk:

```
dmax <- max(apply(dmat,2,min,na.rm=TRUE))
```

This gives you the maximum distance to the nearest point. If you want to know which points these are, you can take an extra step :

```
which(dmat == dmax, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
# 130 130  59
# 59   59 130
```

So point 130 and 59 are the two points fulfilling your conditions. Plotting this gives you:

```
id <- which(dmat == dmax, arr.ind = TRUE) 
plot(coord)
lines(coord[id[1,],], col = 'red')
```

Note how you get this info twice, as euclidean distances between two points are symmetric (A -> B is as long as B -> A ).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So for `df` as your initial data frame you can perform the following:

```
df<-NULL#initialize object 
for(i in 1:10)#create 10 vectors with 10 pseudorandom numbers each
  df<-cbind(df,runif(10))#fill the dataframe

cordf<-cor(df);diag(cordf)<-NA #create correlation matrix and set diagonal values to NA
```

Hence:

```
             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       [,10]
[1,]          NA -0.03540916 -0.29183703  0.49358124  0.79846794  0.29490246  0.47661166 -0.51181482 -0.04116772 -0.10797632
[2,] -0.03540916          NA  0.47550478 -0.24284088 -0.01898357 -0.67102287 -0.46488410  0.01125144  0.13355919  0.08738474
[3,] -0.29183703  0.47550478          NA -0.05203104 -0.26311149  0.01120055 -0.16521411  0.49215496  0.40571893  0.30595246
[4,]  0.49358124 -0.24284088 -0.05203104          NA  0.60558581  0.53848638  0.80623397 -0.49950396 -0.01080598  0.41798727
[5,]  0.79846794 -0.01898357 -0.26311149  0.60558581          NA  0.33295170  0.53675545 -0.54756131  0.09225002 -0.01925587
[6,]  0.29490246 -0.67102287  0.01120055  0.53848638  0.33295170          NA  0.72936185  0.09463988  0.14607018  0.19487579
[7,]  0.47661166 -0.46488410 -0.16521411  0.80623397  0.53675545  0.72936185          NA -0.46348644 -0.05275132  0.47619940
[8,] -0.51181482  0.01125144  0.49215496 -0.49950396 -0.54756131  0.09463988 -0.46348644          NA  0.64924510  0.06783324
[9,] -0.04116772  0.13355919  0.40571893 -0.01080598  0.09225002  0.14607018 -0.05275132  0.64924510          NA  0.44698207
[10,] -0.10797632  0.08738474  0.30595246  0.41798727 -0.01925587  0.19487579  0.47619940  0.06783324  0.44698207          NA
```

Finally by executing:

```
   max(apply(cordf,2,min,na.rm=TRUE),na.rm = TRUE)#avoiding NA's
```

one can get:

```
[1] -0.05275132
```

the maximum value of the *local* minima.

## Edit:

In order to get the index of matrix

```
>which(cordf==max(apply(cordf,2,min,na.rm=TRUE),na.rm = TRUE))
[1]68 77
```

or in order to get the coordinates:

```
> which(cordf==max(apply(cordf,2,min,na.rm=TRUE),na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   8   7
[2,]   7   8
```

Comment: Please write `TRUE` instead of `T`. Do `T <- FALSE` in your console and run your code again to see why you should.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me, that you have spatial points in some projection. One could argue, that the point furthest away from the rest, is the one which lies furthest from the center (the mean coordinates):

```
library(raster)

set.seed(21)

# create fake points
coords <- data.frame(x=sample(438000:443000,10),y=sample(6695000:6700000,10))

# calculate center
center <- matrix(colMeans(coords),ncol=2)

# red = center, magenta = furthest point (Nr.2)
plot(coords)

# furthest point #2
ix <- which.max(pointDistance(coords,center,lonlat = F))

points(center,col='red',pch='*',cex=3)
points(coords[ix,],col='magenta',pch='*',cex=3)

segments(coords[ix,1],coords[ix,2],center[1,1],center[1,2],col='magenta')
```

[image]

Comment: That's mathematically incorrect. It's not because a point lies the furthest from the center, that the minimum distance to another point from that point is the maximal minimum distance between two points. Try your code on my example and you'll see that you select the wrong point.

Answer (score 1):

To find the points farthest from the rest of the points you could do something like this. I opted for the median distance as you said the point(s) farthest from the rest of the data. If you have a group of points very close to each other the median should remain robust to this.

There is probably also a way to do this with hierarchical clustering but it is escaping me at the moment.

```
set.seed(1234)
mat <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=2), c(-5,5), c(-5.25,4.75))
d <- dist(mat)
sort(apply(as.matrix(d), 1, median), decreasing = T)[1:5]
# 51       52       20       12        4 
# 6.828322 6.797696 3.264315 2.806263 2.470919
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a handy little function you can use for picking from the largest of line distances. You can specify if you want the largest, second largest, and so forth with the `n` argument.

```
getBigSegment <- function(x, y, n = 1){
  a <- cbind(x,y)
  d <- as.matrix(dist(a, method = "euclidean"))
  sorted <- order(d, decreasing = T)
  sub <- (1:length(d))[as.logical(1:length(sorted) %% 2)]
  s <- which(d == d[sorted[sub][n]], arr.ind = T)
  t(cbind(a[s[1],], a[s[2],]))
}
```

With some example data similar to your own you can see:

```
set.seed(100)
mydata <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 438000, 445000) + rpois(10, 440000), 
                     y = runif(10, 6695000, 6699000) + rpois(10, 6996000))

# The function
getBigSegment(mydata$x, mydata$y)
#            x        y
#[1,] 883552.8 13699108
#[2,] 881338.8 13688458
```

Below you can visualize how I would use such a function

```
# easy plotting function
pointsegments <- function(z, ...) {
  segments(z[1,1], z[1,2], z[2,1], z[2,2], ...)
  points(z, pch = 16, col = c("blue", "red"))

}

plot(mydata$x, mydata$y) # points
top3 <- lapply(1:3, getBigSegment, x = mydata$x, y = mydata$y) # top3 longest lines
mycolors <- c("black","blue","green") # 3 colors
for(i in 1:3) pointsegments(top3[[i]], col = mycolors[i]) # plot lines
legend("topleft", legend = round(unlist(lapply(top3, dist))), lty = 1,
       col = mycolors, text.col = mycolors, cex = .8) # legend
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This approach first uses `chull` to identify `extreme_points`, the points that lie on the *boundary* of the given points. Then, for each `extreme_points`, it calculates `centroid` of the `extreme_points` by excluding that particular `extreme_points`. Then it selects the point from `extreme_points` that's furthest away from the `centroid`.

```
foo = function(X = all_points){
    plot(X)
    chull_inds = chull(X)
    extreme_points = X[chull_inds,]
    points(extreme_points, pch = 19, col = "red")
    centroid = t(sapply(1:NROW(extreme_points), function(i)
        c(mean(extreme_points[-i,1]), mean(extreme_points[-i,2]))))
    distances = sapply(1:NROW(extreme_points), function(i)
        dist(rbind(extreme_points[i,], centroid[i,])))
    points(extreme_points[which.max(distances),], pch = 18, cex = 2)
    points(X[chull_inds[which.max(distances)],], cex = 5)
    return(X[chull_inds[which.max(distances)],])
}

set.seed(42)
all_points = data.frame(x = rnorm(25), y = rnorm(25))
foo(X = all_points)
#           x         y
#18 -2.656455 0.7581632
```

[image]